# updating a map column in dataframe spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe origMap with a column that is of type map. I want to add more entries to that map

I'm doing following that's working:

```
val origMap = df("mapping")

val tempMap = tempDFFields.flatMap(tempField => Array(lit(tempField), tempDF(tempField))): _*)

origMap.withColumn("mapping", tempMap.union(origMap))
```

tempDFFields is list of column names in tempDF.

I'm creating a map of all colname->colvalue from tempDF and want to add it to original DF.
It complains that I'm passing array of Column instead of single instance of Column. how can I pass single instance of column here .. I just want to update the map and store it back.

Example:

Input

origDF

```
+--------+-----------------------------
|id  | amount       | mapping         | 
|1   | 10           | {a=b, c=d}      |
|3   | 90           | {e=f, g=h}           |
```

tempDF

```
+-----
|Id |
|1  |
```

output: origDF

```
+--------+-----------------------------
|id  | amount       | mapping          | 
|1   | 10           | {a=b, c=d, id=1} |
|3   | 90           | {e=f, g=h, id=1} |
```

Comment: Can you explain with some input and output data aswell?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala added

Comment: Is the mapping field of type Map, and what is tempDF?

Comment: yes, mapping os of type map. tempDF is another DF.

Comment: always with one column? what if `tempDF` `Id` contains value 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: it could contain multiple columns but only one value for each column

Comment: Can you accept as an answer if the answer worked for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an `udf` to merge the map as below

```
val origDF = Seq(
  (1, 10, Map("a" -> "b", "c" -> "d")),
  (3, 90, Map("e" -> "f", "g" -> "h"))
).toDF("id", "amount", "mapping")

If you have a single row DF you can create a map directly
val tmpDF = Map("id" -> "1")

//UDf to merge the two map 
val addToMap = udf((mapping: Map[String, String]) => {mapping ++ tmpDF})

//Use the udf 
origDF.withColumn("mapping", addToMap($"mapping"))

.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+------+----------------------------+
|id |amount|mapping                     |
+---+------+----------------------------+
|1  |10    |Map(a -> b, c -> d, id -> 1)|
|3  |90    |Map(e -> f, g -> h, id -> 1)|
+---+------+----------------------------+
```

Hope this helps!